# The status of Urdu in Pakistan versus the status of Hindi in India

Tags: india, language, pakistan

This is a critical question because it caused the 1952 language movement in Pakistan.

The Internet says that Urdu is the national language of Pakistan, but that Hindi is not the national language of India. However, practically, both of them are the lingua franca in their respective countries.

How are they dissimilar according to the constitutions of their respective countries?

.

**Note:** I am comparing Pakistan and India. I am comparing Urdu in Pakistan with Hindi in India.

I am not comparing Urdu and Hindi in India. I am not comparing Urdu and Hindi in Pakistan.

.

**Note2:**  I am seeking an explanation of an article of the constitution. That is what Supreme Courts do. Therefore, it should be a legal question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139658/discussion-between-kisspuska-and-user366312).

Answer (score 5):

The difference is mainly terminological. [Article 251](https://www.infopakistan.pk/constitution-of-pakistan/article/251-National-language) of the Constitution of Pakistan says

> 1.The National language of Pakistan is Urdu, and arrangements shall be made for its being used for official and other purposes within fifteen
> years from the commencing day.
>
> 2. Subject to clause (1), the English language may be used for official purposes until arrangements are made for its replacement by
>    Urdu.
> 3. Without prejudice to the status of the National language, a Provincial Assembly may by law prescribe measures for the teaching,
>    promotion and use of a Provincial language in addition to the National
>    language.

[Article 343](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/379861/) says

> (1) The official language of the Union shall be Hindi in Devanagari
> script The form of numerals to be used for the official purposes of
> the Union shall be the international form of Indian numerals (2)
> Notwithstanding anything in clause ( 1 ), for a period of fifteen
> years from the commencement of this Constitution, the English language
> shall continue to be used for all the official purposes of the Union
> for which it was being used immediately before such commencement:
> Provided that the president may, during the said period, by order
> authorise the use of the Hindi language in addition to the English
> language and of the Devanagari form of numerals in addition to the
> international form of Indian numerals for any of the official purposes
> of the Union (3) Notwithstanding anything in this article, Parliament
> may by law provide for the use, after the said period of fifteen
> years, of (a) the English language, or (b) the Devanagari form of
> numerals, for such purposes as may be specified in the law

In other words, in one case the term employed is "national language" and in the other case it is "official language". In either case, national government business is to be carried out in the official / national language, and not in a regional language.

Comment: But, In Pakistan, it is mandatory/compulsory to learn Urdu for every citizen. As a result, they have to take Urdu language courses throughout their high school education. Is it mandatory/compulsory to learn Hindi for every citizen in India?

Comment: @user366312: even if one ignores (political) reality and just sticks to the constitutional texts, the Indian one allows an escape (in clause 3) for English to be continued to be used, whereas the Pakistani constitution doesn't have that (for English).

Comment: @user366312, Sindhi and Pashto are also actual languages of instruction. Seems that your question is more deeply tied to the different degrees of local autonomy in India vs. Pakistan, which is a political issue. Simply put, not every difference practice is the result of there being a law, sometimes it's just differences in political philosophy.

Comment: @user6726, Sindhi, and Pashto are not compulsory nationwide. They are provincial languages.